# Article about free static function usage

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I am looking for an article or documentation that explains why a free static function is better than a private member function, when the given function does not modify or read the private members of the class. To my point of view the advantages are :

- Less dependencies
- Better encapsulation (for "mammoth" classes, it helps to know that at least those function calls do not modify the members)

I am certain someone has already written something better than what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are specifically looking for an article you should read "Item 23: Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions" in [Effective C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) by Scott Meyers. I would suggest that this book is essential reading for all serious C++ programmers.

The basic premise for this topic is that if you can implement a free function using existing interface methods of a class then you should as this actually simplifies the class. That is, the less code that can see the internals of the class the more encapsulated it is. Adding more bloat actually *decreases* encapsulation.

Comment: This is the artile I was thinking about but could not remember. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Free static functions are passe.  One would use a function in the anonymous namespace instead.

They are slightly more maintainable -- since they can't access private members, they are robust against changes to implementation details.  A static member function could also be independent of implementation details, but you don't have the compiler verifying that.

Comment: I like the point you bring : robust against changes to implementation details

Comment: "Free static functions are passe". But entity declared in anonymous namespace has external linkage, so I kept with the old static declaration inside the .cpp due to link time issues. Appart from that, the result is the same not ?

Comment: It has external linkage, which makes it usable with templates, etc.  Otherwise the behavior is the same.  I don't understand why you would have any link time issues because of a function in the anonymous namespace.

Comment: I always believed that the more symbols you have to resolve, the more link time it takes, so this is why I prefer static over anonymous namespace. We must think of it over the entire application, no for a single function. But I should benhmark, it may not make a difference overall.

Comment: @Palmira: Ahh, I had misunderstood.  I thought you meant there were issues during linking ("at link time").  But you mean that linker elapsed time is an issue.  That makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be misusing some words so I'll attempt to clarify

```
class myclass {
private: 
    int data;

    void func1(); // private mutator function
    void func2() const;  // private accessor function
    static void func3();  // private static function
public:
    int moredata;

    void func4(); // public mutator function
    void func5() const;  // public accessor function
    static void func6(); // public static function
}

void func7(myclass); // free function
static void func8(myclass); // static function can't be accessed outside file.
```

Generally, operator overloads tend to free functions so that way they can be found during lookup if a conversion is needed.
Private functions are used when no outside functions or classes will call those functions.
Static functions are used when they do not read or write to a myclass, but are an integeral part of the concept of the class.
Constant functions can be used on `const` objects, and do not modify the class.

Comment: You can use `static` outside of the class to get internal linkage. So `static void func7(myclass);` is legal, too.

Comment: I left it out since he was asking about maintainability of a class, and that's a linkage thing, which isn't really related.  I added it for completion though.

Comment: I think I used the right words. But to be certain I made myself clear. I refer to  `funct8' as static free function (usually found in the .cpp) and to "func2" for private member function.

Comment: Note that `func8` cannot be called from any other `cpp` file.  I doubt that's what you want.  Oh wait nevermind, I just understood what you're doing.  Your terminology is correct.

Comment: yep, thats what I want, just a func8 in the cpp and that is not linked externally. Thanks for clarifying it all!

Answer (score 1):

1. `encapsulation` means combining relevant data and functions. So it's irrelevant here.
2. If a function doesn't change member variables it is marked as `const`, but depending on the context it can still happily belong to a `class` instead of being forced to be a lonely free `static` function.
3. Personally (this can be debated) I believe that you should put together all relevant functions into a single `class` or AT THE VERY LEAST a `namespace` instead of leaving them all alone.

   Though from java, from design pov this is a valid example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html, http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: 1. I disagree, (see next post about Effective C++ article).

Comment: 2. I prefer the free stratic function in the .cpp to make it clear it neither modify or need the private interface in order to function + break dependency

Comment: 3. I think this is not related with my original question I would be one who debate. As a client of the class, I don't like to do "MyClass a; a.doSomething();" everytime. As a general rule, if it is always the same client who build and calls the function before destroying the object... this is not a useful object. I prefer max(a,b) over MaxClass myMaxCalculatorObject; myMaxCalculatorObject.ComputeMax();

Comment: For the article, thanks, it helps me to get your point. Please note that in my case, I am interested in private member (const) functions that do not use any member of the class. What you propose look more like public services regrouped into a class.